# I got error when installing tweepy on anaconda with conda install

Tags: python, anaconda, tweepy

I'm trying to install tweepy on my anaconda (python3.5, windows). 
I searched package:

```
anaconda -t conda tweepy
```

then:

```
conda install -c zed tweepy=3.5.0
```

What I got was error message like 'package miising in current win-64 channels'....

Does anyone know how to install tweepy using conda install? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That channel (`zed`) only has version 2.3. You can see this by going to the anaconda.org website: https://anaconda.org/search?q=tweepy (probably you can get the same information from the CLI search, but I think the web interface is prettier). The `lebpride` channel appears to have 3.5.0, so

```
conda install -c lebpride tweepy=3.5.0
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tweepy

The command is:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tweepy
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. Then I came up with the following solution :

The following method works on Windows :

Step 1 : Click on start

Step 2 : Search and Open Anaconda Navigator

Step 3 : In the Anaconda Navigator, Go to Evironments

Step 4 : There is a drop down menu consisting of options : 1) Installed 2) Not Installed 3) Upgradable 4) Selected 5) All

Step 5 : Click on "Not Installed"

Step 6 : There is a block stating Search Packages, there enter the name of the package you want to install (like enter tweepy if you want to install tweepy).

Step 7 : Mark the name of the package to be installed in the search results, and click Apply

Installation will start.

Congratulations! You have successfully installed the package.

The above method worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

for Python 3.6 on win32, you can run conda-forge. run the following

```
conda install -c conda-forge tweepy
```

more details on https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tweepy